# Where does Outlook 2003 retrieve local time from?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003, time-zone

Windows XP | Outlook 2003

Where does Outlook 2003 specifically retrieve time zone info? Is there an Office setting? Or does it reference the local time-zone?

I have an issue where time stamps in Outlook are 1 hour behind the local system time on the same workstation. It would appear that Outlook is not taking into account the DST time zone offset.

Comment: Are you using an exchange server?

Comment: Are you up to date with windows updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft Exchange Server, it will reffer to this for the time. This will appear in the header. For any email client, email will be sent with time set on the server this email itself is sent from.